# ¿Por que no poner las fechas en un formato estandar?

Tags: discusión

El W3c sugiere en [Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), entre otros, el formato para fechas **YYYY-MM-DD** (2017-02-24) y para fecha-hora **YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD** (2017-02-24T16:01+01:00)). Creo que sería más claro que el empleado del tipo **MMM d 'YY at hh:mm** (Aug 4 '14 at 10:44)

Answer (score 2):

Pues **motivo número 1** y principal, es básicamente porque **no podemos**.
Spanish.SE es una comunidad en fase beta y, como tal, hay muchos aspectos del sitio que no se pueden cambiar: los estilos, las plantillas... y el formato estadounidense de fecha, que es el usado por defecto en toda la red de sitios de la comunidad Stack Exchange.
Los sitios que salen de fase beta, creo que sí pueden adaptar esos aspectos (véase [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)), pero nosotros de momento tenemos que funcionar con el que nos dan.

Luego estaría el **motivo número 2**, y es que estamos en un stack sobre el uso del idioma español, y **en español se usa el formato ascendente**: día, mes, año.
[La RAE es muy clara](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=fecha) a la hora de recomendar que se use siempre este formato, salvo en textos científicos o técnicos de carácter internacional. Y por buenas que sean las respuestas del sitio, no creo que podamos categorizarlas como textos científicos o técnicos :D

De todas maneras, cuando dejas el cursor sobre una fecha, te muestra un *tooltip* con la misma fecha en formato estándar, así que por mi parte no creo que haya necesidad, de momento, de hacer tal cambio.

Comment: Buena idea la del *tooltip*, no había 'sobrevolado' ninguna fecha hasta que lo has comentado. En cuanto a la RAE hay mas de una diatriba contra los académicos en el foro del CVC (ie. [Redireccionar] (http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=52338) ).